# Jupiter Docker: Using pip install in a child docker image

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, confluent-kafka-python

I was trying to run a custom version of a Jupiter notebook image on MacOS, just wanted to install a confluent-kafka library in order to use the kafka python client.

I followed the simple instruction provided in the [docs](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/recipes.html#using-mamba-install-or-pip-install-in-a-child-docker-image). This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook:33add21fab64
# Install in the default python3 environment
RUN pip install --quiet --no-cache-dir confluent-kafka && \
fix-permissions "${CONDA_DIR}" && \
fix-permissions "/home/${NB_USER}"
```

The build works fine but when running this is the error I am getting:

```
[FATAL tini (8)] exec -- failed: No such file or directory
```

Trying to look online but haven't found anything useful.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure why the error and would be curious to understand that better. In the meanwhile I got the notebook working on docker using another base image.

Here it is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM jupyter/minimal-notebook
RUN pip3 install confluent-kafka
```